# Using different token for one license in salesforce

Tags: licenses, userlicense, security-token

We are planning to decrease the licenses in salesforce as a result the users which are involved in the process will be hampered and all records assigned to different owners would be lost.

Is it possible if we create a single login but through Token Id distinguish users in salesforce. I want users to use single license but they should be uniquely identified in salesforce.

Please share your views.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is there no way to determine a user based on a token in Salesforce, sharing a user between multiple people may be in violation of your contract with salesforce, and will cause complications when multiple people are in the system as the same user. For example, they would all share the same recent items list, you would not be able to distinguish between which person created/modified/deleted a record, and so on. If some of your users only need limited access (like management), salesforce has a number of [user licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_understanding_license_types.htm) you can choose from that are less expensive, such as Chatter users, Service Cloud licenses, Salesforce Platform, and so on. You should contact your account executive for options on low-cost licenses that may suit your organization's needs without violating contractual obligations or security risks.